# Why FullSimplify return {} on this solution of ode?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

**Update**: Same result is generated using 13.1

I was calling `FullSimplify` with timeout on solution of ode. The idea if it timesout, then will try `Simplify` on same solution with same timeout.

I was surprised that `FullSimplify` returns `{}` while `Simplify` just returns back same solution as expected, since it has `Solve` as header which Mathematica can't solve.

Is this normal behavior? This looks wrong to me. But may be I am overlooking something.

Why does `FullSimplify` return `{}` here? Is this to be expected?

```
ClearAll[x, y]
ode = (y'[x])^2 == Exp[4 x - 2 y[x]]* (y'[x] - 1)
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now compare

```
 Simplify[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With

```
 FullSimplify[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now I have to change my code to check if the ODE solution has `Solve` in it, and avoid calling `FullSimplify` or `Simplify` so not to lose the solution.

I was getting lots of empty solutions from my test after adding the simplification code, and was wondering what caused it until I found this.

V 13.01 on windows 10.

Comment: Same behavior in _v12.3.1_. In _v9.0.1_ `DSolve` cannot solve the problem (return `{}`.

Comment: Interestingly, `FullSimplify[sol, x ∈ Reals]` does return a non-empty solution and with a degree of simplification.

Comment: Just to compare. In Maple  both `odetest(x-sqrt(-(4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))-1)*exp(8*x-4*y(x)))*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))*arctanh(1/sqrt(-4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))+1))/(2*sqrt(-4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))+1))+(1/2)*ln(exp(-2*x+y(x)))-(1/4)*ln(2*exp(-2*x+y(x))-1)-(1/4)*ln(2*exp(-2*x+y(x))+1)+(1/4)*ln(4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))-1)-_C1 = 0,  (diff(y(x), x))^2 = exp(4*x-2*y(x))*(diff(y(x), x)-1));`

Comment: and  `odetest(x+(1/2)*ln(exp(-2*x+y(x)))-(1/4)*ln(2*exp(-2*x+y(x))-1)-(1/4)*ln(2*exp(-2*x+y(x))+1)+(1/4)*ln(4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))-1)+sqrt(-(4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))-1)*exp(8*x-4*y(x)))*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))*arctanh(1/sqrt(-4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))+1))/(2*sqrt(-4*exp(-4*x+2*y(x))+1))-_C1 = 0,  (diff(y(x), x))^2 = exp(4*x-2*y(x))*(diff(y(x), x)-1));` perform `0`.

Comment: I don't know if you were interested in *simple* solutions, but I just noticed that `C[1] -> Log[c1]/2` turns `y[x]` in my answer into `Log[-Sqrt[c1*(c1 - I*E^(2*x))]]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `FullSimplify` converts `ArcTanh[stuff]` to `-(1/2) Log[1 - stuff] + 1/2 Log[1 + stuff]`, `Solve` returns `{}`.

```
Solve[
 (E^(-2 x) *
   Sqrt[E^(8 x) - 4 E^(4 x + 2 y[x])] * 
   (-Log[1 - E^(2 x)/Sqrt[E^(4 x) - 4 E^(2 y[x])]] + 
      Log[1 + E^(2 x)/Sqrt[E^(4 x) - 4 E^(2 y[x])]])) /
   (2 Sqrt[E^(4 x) - 4 E^(2 y[x])]) +
  y[x] == 2 C[1],
 y[x]]

(*  {}  *)
```

And since `{}` is simpler than `Solve[...]`, `FullSimplify` keeps the result.

---

Maybe it's a bug in `Solve`?

Here's an explicit solution, maybe, to the first implicit solution:

```
implsol = sol[[1, 1]];
subY2U = y[x] -> Log[u*E^(2 x)/2];
newimplsol = implsol /. subY2U // 
   Simplify[#, {x, u} \[Element] Reals && u > 0] & // PowerExpand
newexplsol = 
 Thread[y[x] -> Simplify[Values@subY2U /. Solve[newimplsol, u]]] //
    Map@List //
  DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction
```

> ```
> (*  ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[1 - u^2]] + 2 C[1] == 2 x - Log[2] + Log[u]  *)
> ```
>
> Solve::nongen: There may be values of the parameters for which some or all solutions are not valid.
>
> ```
> (*
> {{y -> Function[{x}, 
>     Log[-E^(2 x) Sqrt[
>       E^(-4 x) (Cosh[C[1]] + Sinh[C[1]])^2 (-I E^(2 x) + 
>          Cosh[C[1]]^2 + Sinh[C[1]]^2 + Sinh[2 C[1]])]]]},
>  ... < 3 more > ...}
> *)
> ```

```
ode /. newexplsol // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  {True, True, True, True}  *)
> ```

Well, I guess the last result means we found solutions, despite the warnings about the parameters.  It's also despite that there are no values of `x` and `C[1]` that satisfy the assumptions `{x, u} \[Element] Reals && u > 0` used in constructing the solution.  None I could find at least.  But the solutions are verified anyway, but whether they represent the general solution is still a question.